# Javascript regex to grab the contents of a p tag

Tags: javascript, regex

can someone help me a code a regex which will grap the contents of this p :

`<p class="bc_shirt_name">101</p>`

Thanks

Comment: Every time you use a regex on HTML a fairy dies...

Comment: @Alnitak and still people are killing her..

Comment: `<p class="bc_shirt_name">101</p>` isn't HTML.

Comment: @SalmanA then what is it..

Comment: @SalmanA please explain your comment.

Comment: It is a string that contains `<` and `>`. You can disagree of course :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways but here is a way to use regex as asked by the original question:

```
var html = "<stuff><p class=\"bc_shirt_name\">101</p></stuff>";

var matches = html.match(/<p\s+class="bc_shirt_name">[\S\s]*?<\/p>/gi);
    matches = matches[0].replace(/(<\/?[^>]+>)/gi, ''); // Strip HTML tags?

alert(matches);​
```

JSFiddle Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/tGTb7/

Comment: Spot on, exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It is preferable to use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) when your markup is well formed.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString('<p class="bc_shirt_name">101</p>', "application/xml");
var contents = doc.documentElement.textContent;
```

This works for pretty much any XML, not just XHTML. I could use this on `<tag>foo</tag>` as well.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/vEeXX/

Comment: @SalmanA An instance of the `DOMParser` constructor is .. well, a `DOMParser`. I've added a link to the MDN docs.

Comment: Reference: [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser).

Comment: how does `application/xml` know that you are looking for data within `<p>`..you **never** specified anything about <p>..`it's like a magic for me`!..i am totally new to this thing..

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ `<p class="bc_shirt_name">101</p>` is well formed XML. I'm just parsing it into an XML document and getting the contents of the root node.

Comment: @SalmanA I think IE7 doesn't support DOMParser, it uses an ActiveXObject that does exactly the same thing. I can't remember the name though.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser should be able to parse HTML, no?

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<p class="bc_shirt_name">101</p>';
var p = div.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var html = p.innerHTML; // content as html
var text = p.textContent || p.innerText; // content as plain text
```

Comment: Expensive. You're injecting the DOM for this?

Comment: @KingKongFrog not expensive really - the created element never actually ends up in the rendered DOM, and setting the `.innerHTML` of a node is something that browsers are _very_ good at.

Comment: Not when it's coming in a plain text ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "<p class="bc_shirt_name">101</p>";
var match, result = "", 
regex = /<p\s+class="bc_shirt_name">(.*?)<\/p>/ig;

while (match = regex.exec(str)) {
  result += match[1]; 
  }
 alert(result);
```

The result variable will contain the required data. hope this helps.

Comment: This just returns an empty string.